# How to add HubSections dynamically that contain a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to describe the problem using an example:

- get a list of video-genre-items (Comedy, Action, ...) each containing a list of video items from a web-server (number of genres and videos is not fix)
- display each genre in a separate HubSection that contains a list of resp. video items
- select video (list item) triggers action (eg. start player, open info box, ...)

What i know:
- add HubSection via c#

myhubtest.cs

```
   HubSection hubSection = new HubSection();
   hubSection.Header = "My Title";
   ...
   this.MyHub.Sections.Add(hubSection);
```

myhubtest.xaml:

```
   <Hub  x:Name="MyHub" SectionHeaderClick="Hub_SectionHeaderClick">
   ...
```

- add a DataTemplate via c#
  myhubtest.cs

  object xHubListTemplate;
  this.Resources.TryGetValue("xHubListTemplate", out xHubListTemplate);
  DataTemplate xHubListDataTemplate = xHubListTemplate as DataTemplate;
  hubSection.ContentTemplate = xHubListTemplate as DataTemplate;

App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="xHubListTemplate">
   <ListView x:Name="xHubListView" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
      Margin="0,0,0,0"
     ...
    </ListView>
 </DataTemplate>
```

How can ItemsSource and ItemsTemplate and ItemClick be assigned?

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsData"/>
</Page.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="xHubListTemplate">
    <ListView x:Name="xHubListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsData}}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="xHubListView_ItemClick" >
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```

in code:

```
private bool LoadData()
{
    this.cvsData.Source = ...... (list of data)
}

private void xHubListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemCLickEventArgs e)
{
}
```